# Does joining table in Spark multiplies selected columns of smaller table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

I have two tables in spark:

```
T1
|--x1
|--x2

T2
|--z1
|--z2
```

- T1 is much larger than T2
- The values in column z2 are **very large**
- There is a Many-One relationships between T1 and T2 respectively (via
  the x2 and z1 columns).

I perform the following query:

```
select T1.x1, T2.z2 from T1
join T2 on T1.x2 = T2.z1
```

In the resulting data set, the same value from T2.z2 will be multiplied to many values of T1.x1.

Since this value is very heavy- I am concerned whether the data is actually duplicated or whether there are internal optimisations that maintain only references?

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer that covers all possible scenarios. The exact behavior will depend on the number of factors:

- Type of join - broadcast joins will duplicate your data across different nodes by definition, hash joins won't.
- Amount of available memory - any data spills that serialize data might duplicate memory requirements of the output.
- Caching, data distribution and data types - Spark uses column-wise not row-wise representation for caching and further uses different compression and encoding techniques on the columns, depending on the data type and runtime statistics.

Only the first bullet is part of public API, the rest is internal and might vary from version to version.

In remaining cases Spark behavior is not different from standard Java / Scala code - references are just references, and I am not aware of any optimizations in this space.

Comment: Note that I am not asking about how the join expression will be evaluated. Given that my result set will have duplicate values because of the join- will spark actually duplicate the data or only the references.

Comment: How it is evaluated is fundamental to the answer

Comment: Fair enough. Suppose data is not serialized - is it still duplicated? also, even if data is serialized form, it is absolutely possible to mark certain values as references to a 'single' value. Since RDDs and data frames are immutable, it feels right to implement such an optimisation. Anyway, I am going to check in a synthetic experiment anyway but was hoping there is some documentation on that..